# Pandas Combining Date and Hour columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to combine 2 columns in my df : hours and date.
here is my data sample :

```
   HOUR   data_date
0     0  2020-06-22
1     1  2020-06-22
2     2  2020-06-22
3     3  2020-06-22
4     4  2020-06-22
5     0  2020-06-22
6     0  2020-06-22
7     0  2020-06-22
8     0  2020-06-22
9     0  2020-06-22
10    1  2020-06-22
11    1  2020-06-22
12    1  2020-06-22
13    1  2020-06-22
14    2  2020-06-22
15    2  2020-06-22
16    2  2020-06-22
17    2  2020-06-22
18    3  2020-06-22
19    3  2020-06-22
20    3  2020-06-22
21    3  2020-06-22
22    3  2020-06-22
23    4  2020-06-22
24    4  2020-06-22
25    4  2020-06-22
26    4  2020-06-22
27    0  2020-06-22
28    0  2020-06-22
29    0  2020-06-22
54    1  2020-06-22
55    1  2020-06-22
56    1  2020-06-22
57    1  2020-06-22
58    1  2020-06-22
59    2  2020-06-22
60    2  2020-06-22
61    2  2020-06-22
62    2  2020-06-22
63    2  2020-06-22
64    2  2020-06-22
65    2  2020-06-22
66    2  2020-06-22
67    3  2020-06-22
68    3  2020-06-22
69    3  2020-06-22
70    3  2020-06-22
```

I tried different solution i searched online such as :

```
data['Datetime'] = [data.loc[x,'data_date'] + dt.timedelta(hours = int(data.loc[x,'HOUR'])) for x in list(data.index)]
```

this returns error of dt not defined.

tried also :

```
pd.to_datetime(data.data_date) + pd.to_timedelta(data.HOUR, unit='h')
```

which gave me this error :
{TypeError}ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

tried also:

```
data['data_date'] +=  pd.to_timedelta(data['HOUR'], unit='h')
```

which gave me this error : TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<U10') and dtype('<m8[ns]')

I want to achieve a new column looking like datetime '2020-06-22 01:00:00'
and I'm really getting frustrated as this should be pretty straight forward [or at least i thought it would be].

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(data.data_date) + pd.to_timedelta(data.HOUR, unit='h')` works fine for me with your data.

Comment: im getting an error when running this code :{TypeError}ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred due to the pandas version once I upgraded my pandas version this stopped from happening.

> so apparently version 0.22.0 is bugged for this specific functionality

Thanks @jezrael for your quick response and help.